# Access videos posted in Windows Azure via Asp.Net

Tags: video, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-web-app-service

I need to recover videos that are published in Azure Web Site. (The site was created just for hosting videos in a folder (Media)). I cannot access these videos.
My idea was to host a banal site and referenced by an XML file to display in a MediaElement control for Windows Phone 8.

1) How can I access these videos, because when I write the url where my videos are stored, I get an error 404.  http://fetchvideos.azurewebsites.net/Media/Video2.mp4 
I tried to change the access rights via FileZilla, but it was denied!

2) If there is no way to access them, you have another solution ? I need a link/nameFile.extension

Thank you and please, excuse my English !!

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bit late, but this can help other people.

This error can come from missing MimeMaps in your configuration.
You need to add the following in your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg"/>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

And add all the types you need.

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/4bba6fa7-1553-4452-a795-c635b60d38ca/video-files-are-not-loaded-and-cannot-be-browsed

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

The error you see states:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Which most probably means you ran out of resources for your **free** Azure Website. Navigate to your Dashboard to check whether you still have resources free to server up your website.

Some restrictions that apply to Free and Shared instances for Azure WebSites are well described [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#header-1). Most important for your case being:

> 165 MB of outbound data per day per sub region, up to 5 GB per
>   region**; unlimited inbound data

So, you could very easily have already reached that limit serving videos.

Comment: Ok, but, the video was never displayed.
I've always had this error!

Comment: did you check your resource usage from the Management portal before posting the comment ?!

Comment: data input : 15.68 Ko
data output : 71.18 Ko
30 requests

Comment: did you upload the videos into /wwwroot/site/Media using FTP, or you just placed "Media" folder in the ROOT of FTP?